# Bash commands not working in pipenv shell

Tags: terminal, macos, django

I am working on learning Django for backend and full-stack development. I have that working with pipenv for virtual environments can be a pain in the rear end (at least on macOS). In the terminal, I get into the pipenv shell and some common bash commands no longer work (e.g. 'ls' and some commands stored to the PATH variable like 'code'). I have attached a video to illustrate how this is not working:

[YouTube video of pipenv shell bash commands not working](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o8k5IjnB60Q)

Has anyone else ever experienced this issue? Thanks!

EDIT: Per userbase request, I have included the text:

```
mbGem:booklist lamidotijjo$ echo $PATH
/opt/homebrew/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/Users/lamidotijjo/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/lamidotijjo/ia:/usr/local/mysql-8.0.31-macos12-arm64/bin:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin
mbGem:booklist lamidotijjo$ pwd
/Users/lamidotijjo/Projects/booklist
mbGem:booklist lamidotijjo$ pipenv install django
Installing django...
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (79baf8)...
To activate this project's virtualenv, run pipenv shell.
Alternatively, run a command inside the virtualenv with pipenv run.
mbGem:booklist lamidotijjo$ pipenv shell
Launching subshell in virtual environment...

The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
bash-3.2$  . /Users/lamidotijjo/.local/share/virtualenvs/Projects-3XO0tcpO/bin/activate
(Projects) bash-3.2$ ls
bash: ls: command not found
(Projects) bash-3.2$ ls -l
bash: ls: command not found
(Projects) bash-3.2$ code
bash: code: command not found
(Projects) bash-3.2$ code .
bash: code: command not found
(Projects) bash-3.2$
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the text.  Videos or images are hard to work with when it comes to code.

Comment: Yes, and all relevant information needs to be in the question itself. Don't expect people to go and watch some video in order to understand the problem. When you edit your question, make sure to also include the output of `echo "$PATH"` before and after entering the pipenv shell.

Comment: Hello ladies and gentlemen, I have added the requested text. Thanks!

Comment: What is your `PATH` after you `activate`? Looks like the env is hosed.

Comment: @triplee, after activate the path is as follows: (Projects) bash-3.2$ echo $PATH
/Users/lamidotijjo/.local/share/virtualenvs/Projects-3XO0tcpO/bin:/Users/lamidotijjo/Library/Python/3.10/bin:{PATH}

Comment: I suggest you use `conda` as package manager.

Comment: That looks like you have a typo in `activate` or somewhere. That should obviously be `/Users/lamidotijjo/.local/share/virtualenvs/Projects-3XO0tcpO/bin:/Users/lamidotijjo/Library/Python/3.10/bin:${PATH}` which expands to your previous `PATH` with these two components added in front of it.

Comment: As a stopgap measure, you can write `PATH=/Users/lamidotijjo/.local/share/virtualenvs/Projects-3XO0tcpO/bin:/Users/lamidotijjo/Library/Python/3.10/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/Users/lamidotijjo/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/lamidotijjo/ia:/usr/local/mysql-8.0.31-macos12-arm64/bin:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin` at the shell prompt after you `activate`, but you should really find that typo and fix it.

Comment: Or maybe just create a new virtual environment and hope that it doesn't have the same problem.

Comment: @tripleee sadly, opening a new virtual environment via pyenv does not fix/address the issue. I have uninstalled pyenv and reinstalled it again and sometimes even outside of the virtual environment, pyenv is not recognized despite placing it in my path. I don't know if this is a Mac thing I wouldn't think that bash on Mac would be too different from say a debian based Linux like Ubuntu. With Ubuntu, everything works the way it is intended.

Comment: Oh the stopgap measure needs quotes around the value; I notice you have some paths with spaces in them. `pyenv` works fine for me on a Mac but I haven't tried `pipenv`. I continue to think it's something in your installation.